# Where can I download the mp3plugin.jar to play MP3s in Java code?

Tags: java, mp3, ubuntu-11.04, jmf, javasound

I need to Play a MP3 File in Java code under Linux environment (**Ubuntu 11.04**).

I tried to download the **MP3plugin.jar** file from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html ,but I can't see it in the list.

Note : "I downloaded the sun Java Media Framework"

Comment: Check out JavaZoom (Google it). It does not require you to install JMF, and will of course run wherever java runs.

Comment: thanks, I'll check about it ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is the link from which I downloaded the Jar some time ago, but it seems broken now.  It leads to a page with a long list of APIs for download, none of which are that archive.  :(

---

Fortunately, I use it in various web start apps.  You can get it direct from my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA).

Comment: Seems to be down. I found another copy: http://gwaeron-game.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/DemoRPG/mp3plugin.jar

Comment: Does anyone have a maven mirror of this JAR?