# PlayN mp3 support UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, audio, mp3, playn

I've been researching for days to figure out how to resolve this with no luck.  The PlayN JavaSound class uses the `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem` class to play sounds, and the mp3 format does not seem to be supported.

> javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio
>   input stream from input stream    at
>   javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1102)
>     at playn.java.JavaSound.init(JavaSound.java:71)
>           ......

I cannot find a lot of information on playing mp3s in Java with the `AudioSystem` class, so I am stuck.  It seems like there is a new way to play mp3s in Java 7 with `javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer`, but I would like to know if anyone knows the answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to download a plugin (I think it was this one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html ). I am not sure if this was the case because I did my setup without Maven.

Comment: Thanks Sefan!  That got it.  I came across that during my searching, but was confused about what jmf was exactly.  It did not seem to be what I was looking for.  Also, the link to the download is broken and no longer points to JavaMP3plugin.zip.  I installed the Java Media Framework that the download points to, but that does not help.  I found the mp3plugin.jar file from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392241/where-can-i-download-the-mp3plugin-jar-to-play-mp3s-in-java-code and followed the instructions on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I used this dependency to setup the mp3spi library which may wrk for your mp3 files:

`compile group: 'com.googlecode.soundlibs', name: 'mp3spi', version: '1.9.5-1'`