# Sending audio stream over TCP, UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, audio-streaming

I have succeeded with sending and reading text and images data over TCP sockets. But I am unable to sending and reading audio stream data.

sample code at server:

```
public class ServerAudio {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocker = new ServerSocket();
            Socket client = null;
            serverSocker.bind(new InetSocketAddress(6666));
            if (serverSocker.isBound()) {
                client = serverSocker.accept();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                while (true) {
                    AudioInputStream ain = testPlay("C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/adios.wav");
                    if (ain != null) {
                        AudioSystem.write(ain, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, out);
                    }
                }
            }
            serverSocker.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static AudioInputStream testPlay(String filename) {
        AudioInputStream din = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            System.out.println("Before :: " + in.available());

            AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
            AudioFormat decodedFormat =
                    new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED, baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                            8, baseFormat.getChannels(), baseFormat.getChannels(),
                            baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
            din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
            System.out.println("After :: " + din.available());
            return din;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return din;
    }
}
```

sample code at client:

```
public class RDPPlayAudioBytes {
    private static Socket socket;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("172.19.1.50", 4444);
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("172.19.0.109", 6666);
            // socket.connect(socketAddress, 10000);
            if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                // DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                while (inputStream != null) {
                    if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        System.out.println(inputStream.available());
                        InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                        System.out.println("********** Buffred *********" + bufferedIn.available());
                        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
                    }
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } /*
           * catch (LineUnavailableException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           * e.printStackTrace(); }
           */catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Where I am getting Exception as

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Where I have observed that server is sending 35394bytes data to client, But at client side we are receiving 8192 bytes data. I am unable to understanding why bytes are missing at client side.

Please help me how to send audio stream over TCP Sockets.

Comment: Just a tip: don't use `available()`. In most cases, it does not what you expect.

Comment: try with this  AudioInputStream ain = testPlay("C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\adios.wav");

Comment: look at this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174813/playn-java-mp3-support-unsupportedaudiofileexception

Comment: Couple of things to check. In testplay, after creating `file`, print the values of `file.exists()`, `file.canRead()`, and `file.getCanonicalPath()`. If that all looks good, try printing the value of  `AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file)`. If that fails, take a good look at your file and make sure it really is a WAV file.

Answer (score 9):

**The Server:** The server just streams the bytes of a sound file. No AudioSytem involved. Pass the sound file as argument:

```
java AudioServer "C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/adios.wav"
```

Code for class AudioServer:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AudioServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected sound file arg");
        File soundFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile(args[0]);

        System.out.println("server: " + soundFile);

        try (ServerSocket serverSocker = new ServerSocket(6666); 
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile)) {
            if (serverSocker.isBound()) {
                Socket client = serverSocker.accept();
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

                byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("server: shutdown");
    }
}
```

---

**The client:** The client can play a soundfile passed via the command-line for testing if it works:

```
java AudioClient "C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/adios.wav"
```

Called with no argument it connects to the server and plays the file received via an Socket:

```
java AudioClient
```

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;


public class AudioClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            // play a file passed via the command line
            File soundFile = AudioUtil.getSoundFile(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Client: " + soundFile);
            try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(soundFile))) {
                play(in);
            }
        }
        else {
            // play soundfile from server
            System.out.println("Client: reading from 127.0.0.1:6666");
            try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666)) {
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    play(in);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Client: end");
    }


    private static synchronized void play(final InputStream in) throws Exception {
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
        try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(100); // given clip.drain a chance to start
            clip.drain();
        }
    }
}
```

---

A utility class used by AudioServer and AudioClient:

```
import java.io.File;

public class AudioUtil {
    public static File getSoundFile(String fileName) {
        File soundFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!soundFile.exists() || !soundFile.isFile())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a file: " + soundFile);
        return soundFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The bytes will be received completely as TCP is reliable. There is another small issue. You need to play the received audio from the audio stream, only creating an audio input stream will not play it. 
There can be different possible techniques for playing the audio received. You can use a **Clip** or **SourceDataLine** from the **Java Sound API**. Also, do not create the AudioInputStream multiple times. Simply create it once and use it.

Here's one of the possible solution you can use for playing the received audio.

```
public class RDPPlayAudioBytes {

private static Socket socket;
private static BufferedInputStream inputStream;

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("172.19.1.50", 4444);
    try {
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6666);

        if (socket.isConnected()) {

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputStream);
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();

            while (inputStream != null) {
                if (clip.isActive()) {

                    System.out.println("********** Buffred *********" + inputStream.available());

                }
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

You may need a different implementation based on your requirement. This is just a demonstration on how you can use the **AudioInputStream** for playing audio using **Clip**. You may notice quite a few changes in the code I have posted. I hope you understand this well.

You may refer the Java Sound API docs to dive into the basics of [playing audio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html).

**NOTE**:

1. Just for your knowledge, you may need to **implement a listener** so that the program do not get closed before the audio clip finishes playing. In the current implementation it won't happen due to the loop used. But it is better to use a listener. You may refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577724/trouble-playing-wav-in-java/577926#577926).
2. You can also read the audio data into byte[] and then play it as soon as it is received. The implementation would change slightly.

Comment: This will never terminate: `inputStream` will never get null. Also this loop and the `clip.isActive()` check will eat all your CPU cycles.

Comment: I agree, but my aim was just to show the usage of a medium to play the sound with the code being posted in the question. I agree that the code can be improved.