# how to attach my mp3 file with generated jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, embedded-resource, jmf

in this code i select mp3 path is "D:/camera.wav". when i make jar file of this code, it play in only my system. please tell me how to add camera.wav file to my project and give that url to my project. because i want same music should play for all systems, even though they don't have that music.

```
import java.io.File; 
import javax.media.Format; 
import javax.media.Manager; 
import javax.media.MediaLocator; 
import javax.media.Player; 
import javax.media.PlugInManager; 
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat; 
public class maintest 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
    //float v=1; 
    Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3); 
    Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG); 
    Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR); 
    PlugInManager.addPlugIn("com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder", 
        new Format[]{input1, input2}, 
        new Format[]{output}, 
        PlugInManager.CODEC ); 
    try 
    { 
        Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new       File("D:/camera.wav").toURI().toURL())); 
        //player.getGainControl().setLevel(v); 
        player.start(); 
    } 
    catch(Exception ex){ 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 
}
```

Comment: AFAIK JMF has limited or no support for MP3.  You might like to take a look at [JavaZoom's JLayer API](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-mp3-using-java-sound-api
even i had same issue

Comment: Did you beside adding jars to eclipse install JMF 2.1.1e to your system and restart your computer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  JMF includes an SPI for decoding MP3 that works with most MP3 files (including VBR).  The only ones it seems to fail on is malformed MP3s (that can typically still be played by more robust players).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have it my head that it doesn't support all formats of mp3, might be mp4, but, technically it doesn't support mp3, without plugin ;) but that's nit picks

Comment: @MadProgrammer , in this code i select mp3 path is "D:/camera.wav". when i make jar file of this code, it play in only my system. please tell me how to add camera.wav file to my project and give that url to my project

Comment: @Pshemo, nope. don't try to import package before add plugin. once u get successfully integrate your plugin to eclipse, then import the package and do your coding.

Answer (score 1):

JMF is .. ancient. it hasn't been maintained/updated for years, so especially if you want to have some "modern" code, JMF is not the best option.

personally, I once created (al be it a simple one) a small mp3 player, using the JLayer library which you can find [here](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)
it has plenty of documentation and examples so it shouldn't take too long to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [MP3 Plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html). Or if that doesn't work, [this plugin](http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html) is also a good resource.

Comment: which is the mp3? 
J A I API 1.1.2_01
J A I API Demo 1.1.2
J A I 1.1.1_01
J A I API Documentation 1.1 Maintenance Release
J A I API Tutorial 1.1
J A I Guide 1.0.1
J A I Image I/O Tools 1.0_01
J A I Image I/O Tools Documentation 1.0_01
J A I ICC Profiles
J 3D 1.5.1
J 3D API 1.4.0_01
J 3D Implementation Documentation 1.4.0_01
JMF 2.1.1e
J Access Bridge for Windows Operating System 2.0.1
J Web Start Sample Applications 1.2
J Look and Feel Graphics Repository 1.0
J L & F Design Guide second edition
J Internationalization and Localization Toolkit 2.0
J Accessibility Utilities 1.3
JIMI SDK

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8392893/418556) for a source on the `mp3plugin.jar`.  Note that with it on the run-time class-path, an MP3 can be played using Java Sound - no requirement for the rest of the JMF.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, in this code i select mp3 path is "D:/camera.wav". when i make jar file of this code, it play in only my system. please tell me how to add camera.wav file to my project and give that url to my project.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse that much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm) for playing MP3's. If you use Netbeans just create a new project and select JavaFX project instaed of a normal Java project