# Audio does not play in JMF framework in java

Tags: java, javasound, jmf

when i am running this code nothing get's played. But there is no error. I am using the cross platform JMF 2.1.1 and have imported JMF.jar file in my netbeans project.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HelloJMF {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Hello JMF Player");
    static Player helloJMFPlayer = null;

    public HelloJMF() {

        try { // method using URL 
            URL url = new URL("file", null, "C:\\Users\\Tamojit9\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MediaPlayer\\src\\sample\\gunaah.mp3");
            helloJMFPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Unable to create the audioPlayer :" + e);
        }

        Component control = helloJMFPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

        frame.getContentPane().add(control, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                HelloJMF.stop();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        helloJMFPlayer.start();

    }

    public static void stop() {
        helloJMFPlayer.stop();
        helloJMFPlayer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HelloJMF helloJMF = new HelloJMF();
    }
}
```

Please help me in finding the error!!!!

Comment: Does your code work with the MP3 files seen on [this page](http://pscode.org/media/#sound)?  BTW - it is not necessary to add the entire JMF to the run-time class-path in order to play an MP3.  Part of JMF (one Jar) is a Service Provider Interface for decoding MP3.  Add that alone to the run-time class-path, and Java Sound should then be able to play an MP3.

Comment: i have only added the jmf.jar file to the classpath.

Comment: Well I'd guess that is the problem.  Dump the JMF Jar, add the SPI & do this with Java Sound.  See the [info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for details.

Answer (score -1):

You have given a `mp3` file but `jmf` alone can't play mp3.
For that you have to use [mp3plugin.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392241/where-can-i-download-the-mp3plugin-jar-to-play-mp3s-in-java-code) file, download the jar and then add to classpath then try again and with your code you can play .wav files.